# Change Phone Ringtone while ringing

Tags: android

I know that Android has a built-in system that lets the user choose a special ringtone for a single phonebook contact/group, but i have to change the ringtone dinamically while calling:

So, I wrote a Service and load it at phone startup, to set a phone listener that captures incoming call, that saves the default phone ringtone (in a Service variable) and change the original ringtone with another one if necessary, then restore the orignal ringtone when the phone state returns idle. Well, i can save the original tone, set the new one, but can't hear the new ringtone, only the old:

Take a look at my code and keep in mind that, when the phone listener chooses if to change the original ringtone or not, the phone is **already ringing.**

So, how can i change the ringtone while the phone is already ringing?

I have `android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS` and `android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE` permissions in my Manifest.

The Service:

```
public class CallFilterService extends Service {

    private Uri originalRingtoneUri;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telephonyManager.listen(new CallFilterListener(this), PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public void saveOriginalRingtone() {
        originalRingtoneUri = RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
    }

    public void restoreOriginalRingtone() {
        RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, originalRingtoneUri);
    }
}
```

The PhoneListener:

```
public class MyPhoneListener extends PhoneListener
{
    private CallFilterService service;
    private Uri specialRingtoneUri;

    public CallFilterListener(CallFilterService service) {
        super();
        this.service = service;
        specialRingtoneUri = setSpecialRingtone();       
    }

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING: {
                service.saveOriginalRingtone();
                if (canChangeRingtone(incomingNumber)) {
                    //When in this if block, the default phone ringtone is already playing.
                    RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, specialRingtoneUri);
                }
                break;
            }
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE: 
            {
                service.restoreOriginalRingtone();
                break;
            }
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just curious. Why would you do that? What's it good for? :)

Comment: I'm doing it for a University Project, using a security system based on cross-platform rdf portable ontologies.

Answer (score 1):

First, create a file with the path and filename:

```
File file = new File(path, songName);
```

Then, prepare the query:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, file.getAbsolutePath());
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "My Song title");
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, 215454);
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "Artist");
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION, 230);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);
```

Then insert it into the database:

```
Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(file.getAbsolutePath());
Uri newUri = this.getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);
```

And finally, set the ringtone:

```
RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
  myActivity,
  RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,
  newUri
);
```

This assumes you have the appropriate permissions. If you target API 23 or above, you have to request the permission at runtime in addition to declaring it in the manifest